# MemoryError while counting edges in graph using Networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx

My initial goal was to do some structural property analysis (diameter, clustering coefficient etc.) using Networkx. However, I stumbled already by simply trying to count how many edges there are present in the given graph. This graph, which can be downloaded [from over here (beware: 126 MB zip file)](https://snap.stanford.edu/data/soc-pokec-relationships.txt.gz) consists of 1,632,803 nodes and 30,622,564 edges. *Please note, if you want to download this file, make sure to remove the comments from it (including the #) which are placed on top of the file*

I have 8 GB of memory in my machine. Are my plans (diameter/clustering coefficient) too ambitious for a graph of this size? I hope not, because I like networkx due to its simplicity and it just seems complete.. If it is ambitious however, could you please advice another library that I can use for this job?

```
import networkx as nx

graph = nx.Graph()
graph.to_directed()

def create_undirected_graph_from_file(path, graph):
    for line in open(path):
        edges = line.rstrip().split()
        graph.add_edge(edges[0], edges[1])

print(create_undirected_graph_from_file("C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\soc-pokec-relationships.txt", graph).g.number_of_edges())
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/USER/PycharmProjects/untitled/main.py", line 12, in <module>
    print(create_undirected_graph_from_file("C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\soc-pokec-relationships.txt", graph).g.number_of_edges())
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/untitled/main.py", line 8, in create_undirected_graph_from_file
    edges = line.rstrip().split()
MemoryError
```

Comment: Not what you asked for, but you could try to increase the size of the networks you can handle by switching to `SNAP`, the C++ system of the project that your dataset came from. They provide Python bindings, available [here](https://snap.stanford.edu/snappy/index.html). Unfortunately it only seems to be available for Python 2.7...

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Indeed I saw that there were python binds for SNAP. I haven't tried it out yet (as I thought that networkx is a bit easier to work with). I will try it out and see whether it is working fine over there. Thanks! If it is not possible over there, I think the only solution would be is to increase the memory size. Although I wonder whether there are other possibilities with limited memory

Comment: @alexis, I was able to count up to 117 million edges using the SNAP Pyton library! Much better in terms of performance as well it seems. Makes me wonder how networkx is using so much memory for only 30 million edges. Thanks -Edit: actually it is obvious since snap uses C/C++ underneath while networkx is purely python.

Comment: Exactly, that's why I suggested it. That said, `networkx` _could_ have used high-performance data structures (e.g. numpy arrays) behind the scenes. But it seems to be achieving its flexibility by using ordinary dicts most of the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One potential problem is that strings have a large memory footprint. Since all of your edges are integers you can benefit by converting them to ints before creating the edges. You'll benefit from faster tracking internally and also have a lower memory footprint! Specifically:

```
def create_undirected_graph_from_file(path, graph):
    for line in open(path):
        a, b = line.rstrip().split()
        graph.add_edge(int(a), int(b))
    return graph
```

I'd recommend also changing your `open` to use contexts and ensure the file gets opened:

```
def create_undirected_graph_from_file(path, graph):
    with open(path) as f:
        for line in f:
            a, b = line.rstrip().split()
            graph.add_edge(int(a), int(b))
    return graph
```

Or the magic one-liner:

```
def create_undirected_graph_from_file(path, graph):
    with open(path) as f:
        [graph.add_edge(*(int(point) for point in line.rstrip().split())) for line in f]
    return graph
```

One more thing to keep in mind. `Graph.to_directed` returns a new graph. So be sure you set graph to the result of this instead of throwing out the result.

Comment: Even with this approach I still get memory peaks of 10GB, so this may still be too much data. I imagine, though, that in the presence of limited memory python will garbage collect more aggressively.

Comment: I appreciate the help Eric, I'll look into in a couple of hours and see whether it helps!

Comment: Thanks again Eric. Unfortunately, the same error occurs. I think that the only solution would be is to increase the RAM.